# CANoe error in write window: "Local RT Kernel: Connection is lost"

Tags: capl, canoe

Iam using CANoe v16 and simulating a configuration with a couple of CAPL nodes. I have been succesfully running the configuration for weeks now.

Since today morning, all I can get when trying to run the simulation is this error from System: "**Local RT Kernel: Connection is lost**" in the write window leading to crash.

I would like to know if anyone has encountered the same and how to tackle this problem . Thankyou

Update: Now after an hour or more, teh connection is established again on its own. Is it like a port for the connection was busy and now it is free again

Answer (score 0):

So the issue has been resolved. The issue could come up in two cases as per my research:

1. We are trying to open multiple instances of CANoe Config at the same
   time
2. An overflow of data occurs during analysis.

The latter was the reason for my error, since I was trying to log some data which overflowed at some points of time.